# how to print time format in yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ using date command in linux

Tags: linux, system-administration

I need time in this format 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ'(e.g 1985-04-12T23:20:50.52Z) using date command in Linux. Can you help me on this?

Comment: Even if this were a programming question, it's inconsistent - do you need fractional seconds or not?  Your example doesn't match your description.

Comment: In the future, this question is a better fit for [unix.se] -- usage of UNIX commands is directly on-topic there, whereas here it's only topical insofar as it constitutes a question about software development.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exact reproduction of Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) (a/k/a Zulu time) with *Hundredths* of a second would require fashioning a custom date string and calling `date -u`.

Note: to address the correct assertion in the comment by Toby Speight that there is a potential for a 1-second difference between the date representation held by `d` and that by `n` in the original answer due to using separate `date` calls, you can alleviate the concern by using a single call to `date` (and thank you again Toby for reminding me we can use `printf` *field-width* modifiers to truncate the nanosecond field), e.g.

```
date -u +'%FT%T.%2NZ'
```

**Example Result**

```
$ date -u +'%FT%T.%2NZ'
2018-04-14T17:45:28.20Z
```

This will avoid the 1-second potential difference due to two `date` calls.

Comment: Thanks, Devid , its work for me. i am using now "date -u +%FT%T%Z"

Comment: Glad it helped. Note the update to address the concern raised by @TobySpeight Since there are two date calls there is a potential the date representations can be 1-second off. You can use a single date stamp time and then manipulate the resulting date and time with parameter expansions.

Comment: @TobySpeight, thank you, a better option would be `d=$(date -u +'%FT%T.%N'); d="${d%???????}Z"`. Updated.

Comment: @AnkurGupta - if this answer was helpful, don't forget to select it as solving your problem, if another answer was more helpful, select that one. If you don't select an answer as solving your problem this question will keep bouncing around in the unanswered queue.